# Postgres: monitor what part of the execution plan is running for long queries

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan, long-running-processes

The information in `pg_stat_activity` is sort of scarce, and does not give progress information for long queries.

This information is sort of available in `v$session_longops` in Oracle, which gives which object is being processed (`target`), the number of items it needs to go through (`totalwork`), and the number of item done so far (`sofar`). One can then use that to infer what part of the execution plan the engine is in. This information is available in Spark and Flink as well.

I was wondering if there was a way to have access to that in Postgres, either in system tables, or by observing the processes, or where one might look in the internals if he wants to implement a patch.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no existing feature to monitor long running queries in detail (there is such a feature only for [3 DDL statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/progress-reporting.html)).

A patch has been proposed 3 years ago. It looks like it was not integrated.

See discussion in hackers mailing list:
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CADdR5nxQUSh5kCm9MKmNga8+c1JLxLHDzLhAyXpfo9-Wmc6s5g@mail.gmail.com